# Creating a DNN Module that uses a end-user modifyable template

Tags: asp.net, module, dotnetnuke

I'd like to create a module in DNN that, similar to the Announcements control, offers a template that the portal admin can modify for formatting.  I have a control that currently uses a Repeater control with templates.  Is there a way to override the contents of the repeater ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate, and FooterTemplate properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are many different ways that you can accomplish this, typically the best/easiest manner is to simply put a literal control in for Header, Footer, and Item templates.  Then handle the ItemDataBound event, you can look at the item type and take a specific action on it there to load the needed data.

If you want to see some implementations of this model, you can download the code for my Expandable Text/HTML module, as well as my Guesbook Module both available for free, without login at http://www.iowacomputergurus.com

Answer (score 1):

You can see examples of templating in the default Starertkit module, the FAQ module, repository module and UDT.  All of these have varying levels of control for templating.